# Is there any way to call JLabel by integer

Tags: java, jlabel, imageicon

I am trying to call a Label by integer number. Such as if N = 1, it will return label, if N = 2, it will return label2. I have tried with  **Map** but I can't think properly.

```
Map<Integer, String> box = new HashMap();
{
        box.put(1, "label");
        box.put(2, "label2");

}

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon("BlackKnight.png");
    label.setIcon(image1);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
    ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon("BlackBishop.png");
    label2.setIcon(image2);
```

Trying to give a pseudo code:

input N

output Nth Label name

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do anything with your HashMap. How are you using it?

Comment: First off it would be more like this... `Map<Integer, JLabel>`

Comment: I think the real question here is what are you trying to do? Why do you need to call components via a number?

Comment: I need to add component (images ) randomly in JPanel or JButton. For randomize I use random number. That's why I am trying to call by number. @blahfunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want your label's name, you can simply call: `box.get(1)` to get the name of label1, or `box.get(n)` for the n'th label.

If you want to actually get the entire JLabel, you can change the map to: `Map<Integer, JLabel> box = new HashMap();` and use `box.put(1, label);` and `box.put(5, label5);` etc which you can later call back using the same `box.get(n)` method described above.

In the latter case, you'll have to create the labels first before putting them inside the map though

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Map<Integer, JLabel>`

```
Map<Integer, JLabel> map = new Hashmap<>();

JLabel first = new JLabel("I'm first");
JLabel second = new JLabel("I'm second");

map.put(1, first);
map.put(2, second);

// Will print all the texts from the JLabels
for (JLabel j : map) {    
   System.out.println(j.getText());
}
```

---

I personnally would have used a `List<JLabel>` since lists are ordered.